# Attribute in xml (ASP.NET, C#) - TreeView1.SelectedNode.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I need your support because I have got very difficult problem. I would like to take attribute using TreeView1.SelectedNode but I do not know what should I write there to get  attribute.

This is my Xml tree:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ubrania>
  <damska>
    <nk id="Nowa Kolekcja">

      <item>
        <id>1</id>

      </item>
      <item>
        <id>2</id>

      </item>

    </nk>
    <pm id="Nowosci">

      <item>
        <id>3</id>

      </item>
      <item>
        <id>4</id>

      </item>

    </pm>

  </damska>


</ubrania>
```

IF I will write this: (when I will click on node "nk" I get only value "nk" but I need attribute "Nowa Kolekcja" when I will click on "nk")

```
protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label2.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Value;
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using asp:XmlDataSource and asp:TreeView. you have to setup   for the Value of TreeNode.
Following is my test code:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/XMLFile1.xml">
</asp:XmlDataSource>

<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" 
    onselectednodechanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged">
    <DataBindings>
        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="nk" TextField="#Name" ValueField="id" />
    </DataBindings>
</asp:TreeView>
```

TextField="#Name" means displaying element name.

ValueField="id" means set Value of TreeNode as the content of id attribute.

C# code is simple:

```
protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string attr = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Value;
}
```